# Singular points of the commutator map

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, matrix-rank, math-software

I would like to determine the singular points and the singular values of the polynomial map $f\colon\mathbb{R}^8\to\mathbb{R}^5$
\begin{multline*}
f(x_1,\ldots,x_8)=(x_1x_4-x_2x_3,x_5x_8-x_6x_7,x_2x_7-x_3x_6,\\ x_1x_6+x_2(x_8-x_5)-x_4x_6,x_1x_7+x_3(x_8-x_5)-x_4x_7)
\end{multline*}
motivated by the study of the pairs of matrices $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
x_1&x_2\\ x_3&x_4
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $B=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
x_5&x_6\\ x_7&x_8
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ that commute in $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$:
$$AB=BA\Leftrightarrow f(x_1,\ldots,x_8)=(1,1,0,0,0).$$
$$D_{(x_1,\ldots,x_8)}f=\begin{pmatrix}
x_4 & -x_3 & -x_2 & x_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x_8 & -x_7 & -x_6 & x_5\\
0 & x_7 & -x_6 & 0 & 0 & -x_3 & x_2 & 0\\
x_6 & (x_8-x_5) & 0 & -x_6 & -x_2 & (x_1-x_4) & 0 & x_2\\
x_7 & 0 & (x_8-x_5) & -x_7 & -x_3 & 0 & (x_1-x_4) & x_3
\end{pmatrix}.$$
$(x_1,\ldots,x_8)$ is a singular point of $f$ if and only if $\mathrm{rank} D_{(x_1,\ldots,x_8)}f<5$.  I have to compute $C^3_8=56$ determinants, although the above matrix has some symmytries with respect to $(x_1,\ldots,x_8)$.

> Is there a free scientific software (preferably on Linux) or a free platform for calculating determinants (without doing any programming code).

> Is there any other techniques to determine the singular points of this map without calculating determinants

Comment: Several points seems strange to me in your question. The matrix $AB-BA$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix, and so has $4$ coefficients. The condition $AB-BA=0$ therefore translates into four equations (or possibly less if there are redundancies), so $f$ should be ${\mathbb R}^8 \to {\mathbb R}^4$, not  ${\mathbb R}^8 \to {\mathbb R}^5$. Also, I don't see where your ones come from in your $AB=BA\Leftrightarrow f(x_1,\ldots,x_8)=(1,1,0,0,0).$

Comment: @EwanDelanoy there are two redundant equations (so 3 equations) + 2 equations translating $\det A=1$ and $\det B=1$ ($A,B\in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$...so 5 equations.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried https://matrixcalc.org/en/?

Comment: A slightly different question is well-studied: Consider the commutator map $F: SL(2, R)\times SL(2,R)$, $F(A,B)=ABA^{-1}B^{-1}$. It is known that a pair $(A,B)$ is a critical point of this map if and only if $A, B$ commute. The answer is also known if you consider the same map for $SL(n,R)$-matrices.

Comment: @温泽海 Many thanks for the nice link!

Comment: @MoisheKohan May you provide some details or a reference for the result you mentioned?